# TextBox SelectionStart is always 0 with custom style

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-style

I have a TextBox input field with a custom style:

```
  <TextBox  Style="{StaticResource SettingsTextBoxHint}" KeyDown="textBoxInput_KeyDown" PreviewKeyDown="textBoxInput_PreviewKeyDown"  Name="TextBoxInput" Text="{Binding TextBoxInput, Mode=TwoWay}" Tag="{lex:LocText TypeAMessageHere}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,33,0"/>
```

To which I added the custom style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="SettingsTextBoxHint" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">

                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="White"
                        Padding="1,2,5,2"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                        ToolTip="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 x:Name="textSource" 
                                 Background="Transparent" 
                                 BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                 TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                                 Panel.ZIndex="2"
                                 FontSize="12">
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">

                                                <Border x:Name="Border"
                                                        Background="Transparent"
                                                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                                        CornerRadius="0">
                                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>

                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                        <TextBox  Margin="0,3,0,0" BorderThickness="0" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource RobotoRegularFont}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#cccccc"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="textSource" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=textSource}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The point of which is to make the TextBox transparent and to add hint functionality which text is set trough Tag.

Everything works exactly as I want. The problem I have is that I am writing a new functionality in which I need the position of cursor in the TextBox. But SelectionStart or CaretIndex always return 0 value. If I remove my style I get the correct value.

Can anyone tell me what I missed?

Comment: Do you need the position of the _cursor_ or the position of the _caret_?  Regardless, the problem is likely related to the fact that your `TextBox` template contains two additional `TextBox` controls.  Pro tip: if you want to override a control's template, start with the default template and work from there.

Comment: I need the cursor position. I tried commenting out the second textbox control for the hint but the problem persists.

Comment: And how do you expect the WPF should behave? You have two TextBoxes inside a TextBox. Should they both keep the SelectionStart and CaretIndex in sync? Anyway, you had to create a UserControl if you want to compose multiple controls together, not a style.

Comment: To be honest I just copied the code to make a hint on a TextBox from a example and didn't give it a second thought until now. Guess I will have to find a different way to make hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `TextBox` *within* a `TextBox`.  The user interacts with the *inner* text box, whose text, caret position, etc. are in no way related to the *outer* text box.

Let me clean up your style for you:

```
<Style x:Key="SettingsTextBoxHint"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Hint"
                       Margin="3,1"
                       Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                       FontStyle="Italic"
                       Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"
                       Visibility="Hidden" />
          </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
            <Setter TargetName="Hint" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

To find the cursor position within the `TextBox`, you can use `Mouse.GetPosition(your_text_box)`.  To get the *caret* position within the text, use the `CaretIndex` property.  Note, however, that `CaretIndex` is ***not*** a dependency property, so it does not raise change notifications.  Thus, you cannot bind to it and expect the binding target to be updated.